# Vue a-href download without exact filename

Tags: javascript, vue.js, download, href

I'm working with Vue2. I have exe files with different versions. I have to make a <a> for downloading the latest version file of them.

Home.vue :

```
<template>
    ...
    <a :href="downloadLink" download>
        Latest Version Download
    </a>
    ...
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Home',
    data() {
        return {
            downloadLink: 'Program_v1.10.2.exe'
        }
    }
    ...
}
</script>
```

files in my web server :

```
css (dir)
js (dir)
index.html
Program_v1.10.2.exe
Program_v1.10.3.exe
Program_v1.11.0.exe
...
(Program_v#.#.#.exe files will have been added)
```

How can I download the exe file of latest version when I click the <a> of 'Latest Version Download'?

Comment: You'll need to get the list of your files, find the latest and pass it down to your `a` tag. Where are those files stored? Do you have it locally? I'm not sure how you can make a dir glob access from the frontend tho.

Comment: The simplest way would be to have a latest symlink on the server, that point to the correct file, when you upload a new version, you change that symlink. You will need to allow symlinks in your webserver though. An alternative is to have an endpoint on your server that redirect to the correct file on the fly

Comment: @kissu those files are stored in IIS web server. I think you seems to say there's no dir-glob-access in frontend...

Comment: Yeah, using a server is still the easiest way to go when working with Vue.